# .ftpaccess file and Pure-FTPD

Tags: ftp

I've been looking for a way to have specific users who have access my FTP to have read-only permission on particular directories. I came across some articles on creating .ftpaccess files (which I've read are similar to .htaccess files) to create customized configurations for specific directories and sub-directories.

After reading everything I could find about .ftpaccess files through Google and attempting to create said files I've had no luck.

Does anyone know the syntax that is needed to get these files to work? And is there a particular setting that I need to have enabled to enable these files? I've looked through the conf files but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Pure-FTPd doesn't support per directory access control. [`.ftpaccess`](http://www.proftpd.org/localsite/Userguide/linked/x1021.html) belongs to ProFTPD.

You probably want to switch to ProFTPD with something like this:

```
<Directory /path/to/particular/directory>
    <Limit CWD PWD DIRS READ>
        AllowUser specific_user
    </Limit>

    <Limit ALL>
        DenyUser specific_user
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```